# Updating Schematic Component/Footprint in Altium Designer 15.0

Tags: schematics, altium, footprint, library, update

I am building a library for Altium Designer version 15.0 and have a schematic component as well as a PCB footprint. The footprint is linked to the schematic through the dialog opened when I double-click the component in the schematic library and add the footprint there. If I then edit the footprint later on, do I need to re-add it to the component through the schematic library, or is it updated automatically? I'm leaning towards the latter but want to be certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been continuing my work on the libraries and it appears that it does NOT update automatically. Perhaps there is some configuration somewhere, but it looks like the default requires you to remove the old footprint and re-add the updated one.

Comment: In Altium, once you place a component on a schematic sheet it is fixed and will never ever change. Unless you are using the commands "Update from libraries" (in the schematic) or "Update footprints" (in the PCB, might be named a little different)

Comment: Thanks very much @TomL. That's pretty much what I figured out, though I didn't think to use the "Update from libraries" command. Would that update the footprint for a component if the footprint itself changed?

Comment: It would update the reference to the footprint (which footprint is used) - if you use the fully replace option in that dialog. If it doesn't change the name, you will still need to to an update footprints in the PCB command. It's good to have these two commands in your review checklist.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. I was asking because I was putting together a library containing a lot of SMD parts, and after linking the footprints to the schematic symbol I noticed that one of the footprints was a little too long (the pads were too far apart). I moved the pads closer together and save. I want to update the schematic library's reference to the PCB footprint library so that it links the fixed footprint to that schematic symbol.

Comment: In that case, run Update from libraries when a schematic document is open (with the fully replace option selected). After that, run Design->Update PCB Document and the changes should be automatically transferred to the PCB. You might want to make a commit to your VCS before those operations :)

Comment: Well thank you very much, you've been a huge help! I still think it would be nice if it updated automatically, but oh well, can't have everything ;)

Answer (score 2):

Two why to doing this:

1-go to your PCB component library and select : **TOOLS >> Update  PCB with ll Footprints**, which change all PCB that used this library in any project !!!

like this :

[image]

2- Save the new PCB component library with new name, In Schematic of those project go to:

**TOOLS >> Footprint manager** then select all component which you want to change it's footprint PCB library and in right part  select edit option and change those component footprint then select **Validate >> Accept Changes (Create ECO)**

Like this:

[image]
, Then from **TOOLS >> Update From Library >> Next >> Finish**, Then From **Design >> Update PCB Document ...**

like this:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I know how to update them manually, I was asking if it updated the link between the schematic library and pcb library (footprint) automatically.

Answer (score 0):

After you modify your `.PcbLib` or `.IntLib`…

## Updating footprints in a `.SchDoc`

> `Tools → Update from libraries…`

[image: Updating footprints in a .SchDoc in Altium]

You can update the footprints of components that are already placed on a schematic circuit diagram (`.SchDoc`) according to the component libraries (`.PcbLib` or `.IntLib`) that your project is currently referring to.

## Updating footprints in a `.PcbDoc`

> `Tools → Update from PCB libraries…`

[image: Updating footprints in a .PcbDoc in Altium]

[image: The “Update from PCB libraries” window]

You can then update the footprints of components that are already placed on a PCB layout (`.PcbDoc`) as well.

Comment: (you can get proper looking screenshots from https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/workspacemanager-dlg-pcblibupdateformupdate-from-pcb-libraries-ad?version=15.1). To anyone reading this answer, bear in mind the screenshots as pr 20240125 are taken not from AD15, but something after AD18, when the dark grey theme was introduced.